# Force proxy for non domain computers

Tags: proxy, cisco, access-control-list

So I have had extremely bad results with bridged firewalls so have decided to create a standalone proxy, the pc's on the domain get the proxy by default and their internet access is then filtered. All good!

But then of someone brings a pc in that isn't on the domain, they aren't going through the proxy so can access the internet unrestricted, this is the same as the wifi, devices not on the domain have fully accessible internet

My router is a cisco 2811 and dhcp runs on my DC, what can I do to force all data to pass through the proxy so all traffic is filtered even if they aren't on the domain getting group policy?

Answer (score 1):

> what can I do to force all data to pass through the proxy so all traffic is filtered even if they aren't on the domain getting group policy?

You will need to either:

- Require users of third-party devices on your network to **explicitly configure the proxy server** in their device/browser when they connect to your network.

  This is a policy change, not a technical one; it can also be burdensome on your support team, as users are typically not familiar with the process for configuring a proxy server.
- Enable your proxy as a **transparent proxy** by configuring your gateway device to pass outbound web (HTTP) traffic to your proxy for filtering and onward delivery. In my experience, this is the most effective approach, although you might choose to combine it with the above methods, especially if your proxy provides different levels of filtering via user authentication.

It is also possible to use automated mechanisms for configuring proxy servers, using a PAC file and automatic proxy discovery. However, as noted in the comments, these have critical security vulnerabilities and are not recommended ([source](https://googleprojectzero.blogspot.co.uk/2017/12/apacolypse-now-exploiting-windows-10-in_18.html)).

> [If] someone brings a pc in that isn't on the domain, they aren't going through the proxy so can access the internet unrestricted

**Any solution to this problem will require that you block direct, unrestricted access to the web in your firewall or gateway device.** Without this precaution, the owner of an unmanaged device can simply configure their device to ignore any proxy settings you push to their device (irrespective of deployment method) and gain unrestricted access. This may also be true for your corporate machines, depending on the level of restriction you apply via policy (e.g. can users install their own browser to bypass the group policy-enforced proxy settings?).

This might mean creating ACLs which deny access for web (HTTP) traffic, or configuring transparent proxy rules to pass such traffic automatically to your proxy server. Only the proxy server should have rules which permit direct access to the world-wide web.

You may choose to perform this filtering at the TCP layer by blocking obvious web ports (80/443) or blocking all outbound ports (most secure). Alternatively, you may have the facility to perform this filtering at a higher-layer for any traffic which *looks like* HTTP by performing deep-packet inspection.

Comment: Is there any chance that you could give some examples of ACL's that I could use. Some extra details: proxy is 10.1.1.78 and the ip structure is 10.1.x.y where x is the vlan ID and y is 1-254 (24 bit mask) and cisco router is 10.1.1.253

Comment: Create an allow rule to allow 10.1.1.78 to communicate with any external host (typically expressed as 0.0.0.0/0) on ports 80 and 443. Create a rule with lower precedence (that's important) to deny access to those ports to 10.1.0.0/16. This ensures the proxy has web access while all other machines are denied such access.

Comment: Why the /16 when my subnet mask is /24? @Cosmic Ossifrage

Comment: Good question. I'm assuming you want traffic from all VLANs to be forced out via the proxy. Use a /16 to aggregate over your per-VLAN-assigned subnets, so you only need one rule to handle traffic from any VLAN. 10.1.0.0/16 will deny traffic from any host in 10.1.0.0 through 10.1.255.255.

Comment: WPAD is a critical security risk and shouldn't be used.  https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2016/07/new-attack-that-cripples-https-crypto-works-on-macs-windows-and-linux/  https://googleprojectzero.blogspot.com/2017/12/apacolypse-now-exploiting-windows-10-in_18.html

Comment: @GregAskew Thanks. Wasn't aware of that. Will amend answer accordingly.